# How to do this on my Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to show my action bar like the following pic.

[image]

Comment: What did you try ? What problem did you face ?

Comment: @gahfy 
https://ibb.co/jBM9Sc

That's how my action bar looks. I want to modify this like the above pic mentioned in question

Comment: What did you try ? What problem did you face ? (no, the question was not what your action bar looks now or what do you would like it to look like)

Comment: I did't face any problem. I am a newbie in android so I don't know what I have to do in order to make my action bar beutiful.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat unclear but from what I understand you want to use the `<Toolbar>` XML tag, more info here: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

If this is the answer you're looking for I sugggest creating a BaseActivity that initializes the Toolbar for each activity.

Comment: that's my toolbar link :- https://ibb.co/jBM9Sc . I want it to look like this, link :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2dSL.jpg

Comment: Still unclear, You want it to have the opacity in the photo?

Comment: 1. I want to add my custom textview at center. 2. I want to add that gradient effect over the action bar 3. I want to customize my toolbar